# How can I get synced bookmarks using Selenium?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

I could sign in to chrome using Selenium(Ruby), but could not get synced bookmarks.

I googled how to sign in to chrome using Selenium.
After sign in, chrome showed a dialog which said “sync is disabled by your administrator”.

My account is not G-Suite, but just a personal account which I have just create. I did not disable sync.
I do not want to use user’s profile. I want to do this using id and password.

Can I do this by adding some parameters to Selenium?
Is there a good way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a bit late, but I had a similar situation and I found how to overcome this. The answer is also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51612549/chrome-from-selenium-wont-sync#51613492) but for convenience, I write it below.
So when you open chrome from selenium the `--disable-sync` argument is by default attached to the instance. So you have to exclude it first like this:

```
options.add_experimental_option(
    'excludeSwitches',
    ['disable-sync'])
```

and then to re-enable it like this:

```
options.add_argument('--enable-sync')
```

Note that in order to have something to sync you need to run selenium with a user profile using the --user-data-dir=PATH-TO-PROFILE argument.