# Chrome from selenium won't sync

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, synchronization

I am trying to open up a selenium browser with sync option enabled. Either I specify `--used-data-dir` (having all the cookies and extensions from my google account loaded on selenium) or I don't, it stills won't allow me to sync. A way to check if the browser is allowed to sync is to go to settings -> people. If the browser is syncing a *Sync on* label/option must exist under your account name. If the browser is not syncing then this option is not there, and so you cannot change it.

I have also tried changing the chrome policy *DisableSync* globally from the `registry edit` as specified [here](https://superuser.com/questions/937655/sync-chrome-bookmarks-without-admin-access), but still, selenium won't sync (even if in *chrome://policy/*  the *SyncDisabled* policy is set to *false*).

Won't sync means that if e.g. I add/change a password from a site, the new password won't be stored in my account's cookies, which is basically my objective.  Just to clarify, when I open chrome normally (not selenium) then, of course, the sync option is available.

So, my question I guess is how I can open chrome through selenium having the sync option enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution. So when you start chrome through selenium, even if you are not specifying the *--disable-sync* argument, it specifies it itself. In other words, visiting *chrome://version* in a newly generated selenium browser on the list of *command lines* there is the `--disable-sync` argument. So basically I first excluded it like so:

```
options.add_experimental_option(
    'excludeSwitches',
    ['disable-sync'])
```

and then I enabled it like so:

```
options.add_argument('--enable-sync')
```

since if didn't excluded it before enabling it, both the `--disable-sync` and the `--enable-sync` would be in the *command lines* list.